# How to get some layers from trained model and put them into another to make predictions in tensorflow keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm having problems using functional api for estimating [image: normal] by maximizing [image: proba]

First I minimize the error vector by maximizing the probability layer loss, and then I want to use the mean vector layer to rank `xc_hat` similar embeddings.

The code is as follows:

```
import random as rdn
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
tf.enable_v2_behavior()
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

tfd = tfp.distributions

n_observations = 2000
n_features = 5
d_dim = 3
lr = 0.005

# Generate toy data
def make_relations(x_tr, y_tr, c_tr):
  # Generate input data centers being labels (xc) for two random 
  # in-cluster (xa, xb)
  xa = []
  xc = []
  xb = []

  for l in y_tr:
    kone = [k for k, lab in zip(x_tr, y_tr) if lab==l]
    if len(kone) < 3:
      continue
    for i, x in enumerate(kone):
      if np.isclose(x, c_tr[l]).all():
          continue
      kone_minus_x = kone.copy()
      kone_minus_x.pop(i)
      print
      xa.append(x) 
      xc.append(c_tr[l])
      xb.append(rdn.choice(kone_minus_x))

  return np.vstack(xa), np.vstack(xb), np.vstack(xc)


X, Y, C = make_blobs(n_samples=n_observations, 
                                      n_features=n_features, 
                                      centers=int(n_observations*0.2),
                                       return_centers=True)
x_a, x_b, x_c = make_relations(X, Y, C)

Xa_train, Xa_test = train_test_split(x_a, test_size=.4)
Xb_train, Xb_test = train_test_split(x_b, test_size=.4)
Xc_train, Xc_test = train_test_split(x_c, test_size=.4)

Xa_train = Xa_train[np.newaxis]
Xb_train = Xb_train[np.newaxis]
Xc_train = Xc_train[np.newaxis]

Xa_test = Xa_test[np.newaxis]
Xb_test = Xb_test[np.newaxis]
Xc_test = Xc_test[np.newaxis]

neg_log_likelihood = lambda y, rv_y: -rv_y.log_prob(y)

ones_train = tf.keras.backend.ones((1, Xc_train.shape[1], d_dim)).numpy()
ones_test = tf.keras.backend.ones((1, Xc_test.shape[1], d_dim)).numpy()

# Build model.
xa_xb = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, n_features), name='Xa-Xb')
L_xa_xb = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_dim, activation='sigmoid', name='L_Xa-Xb')(xa_xb)

xb = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, n_features), name='Xb')
L_xb = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_dim, activation='sigmoid', name='L_Xb')(xb)
mu = tf.keras.layers.Add(name='mean_vector')([L_xa_xb, L_xb])

xc = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, n_features), name='Xc')
L_xc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_dim, name='L_Xc')(xc)

error_vector = tf.keras.layers.Subtract(name='error_vector')([L_xc, mu])

p_xc_given_xa_xb = tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
    lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=tf.exp(t)), name='Gaussian')(error_vector)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[xa_xb, xb, xc],
                       outputs=p_xc_given_xa_xb, name="inner_model")
model.compile(
      optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr),
      loss=neg_log_likelihood)
model.fit([Xa_train - Xb_train, Xb_train, Xc_train], ones_train,
          validation_data=([Xa_test - Xb_test, Xb_test, Xc_test], ones_test),
          epochs=1000,
          verbose=True)
    
# After trained rebuild the part of the model I will use for prediction

xa_xb = model.get_layer('Xa-Xb')
L_xa_xb = model.get_layer('L_Xa-Xb')(xa_xb)

xb = model.get_layer('Xb')
L_xb = model.get_layer('L_Xb')(xb)
xc = model.get_layer('mean_vector')([L_xa_xb, L_xb])

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[xa_xb, xb],
                       outputs=xc, name="inner_model")

xc_hat = model([Xa_test - Xb_test, Xb_test])
```

The idea is to estimate `xc` However, I have the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-57-d94b1e8a583c> in <module>()
      2 
      3 xa_xb = model.get_layer('Xa-Xb')
----> 4 L_xa_xb = model.get_layer('L_Xa-Xb')(xa_xb)
      5 
      6 xb = model.get_layer('Xb')

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    966           with base_layer_utils.autocast_context_manager(
    967               self._compute_dtype):
--> 968             outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    969           self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
    970           self._set_mask_metadata(inputs, outputs, input_masks)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py in call(self, inputs)
   1178 
   1179   def call(self, inputs):
-> 1180     rank = inputs.shape.rank
   1181     if rank is not None and rank > 2:
   1182       # Broadcasting is required for the inputs.

AttributeError: 'InputLayer' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Im usign Google Colaboratory

Comment: After training, you simply need to build your model in this way: tf.keras.Model(inputs=[xa_xb, xb], outputs=mu, name="inner_model") no need to make strange extarction

Comment: Thank you @MarcoCerliani, the problem is that `xc` is only in the training set. How to generate it from the trained model from `xa` and `xb`?

Comment: I simply rewrite what you are trying to do below "After trained rebuild the part..." so it's correct